# Как обратиться к элементу обьекта, значение свойства которого совпадает с элементом другого массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```
let mas =["обьект1","Обьект2","Обьетк3","Обьект4"];
```

И массив обьектов

```
let mas1=[
    {
        nameObj:'обьект4',
        value: 14
    },
    {
        nameObj:'обьект1',
        value: 16
    },
    {
        nameObj:'обьект2',
        value: 17
    }
];
```

Как выдергивать из второго массива именно то значение value, свойство nameObj которого совпадает со значение i-го элемента  первого массива.

В цикле перебираем элементы массива:

```
for (let i= 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
   a=?
    //console.log(a);
}
```

т.е. первый элемент обьект1, значит выводиться должно 16 и т.д.

Comment: такая себе затея, лучше хранить объекты в объектах для таких целей, так можно будет задать для внутреннего объекта уникальный ключ и доставать уже по нему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let mas =["обьект1","Обьект2","Обьетк3","Обьект4"];
let mas1=[
    {
        nameObj:'обьект4',
        value: 14
    },
    {
        nameObj:'обьект1',
        value: 16
    },
    {
        nameObj:'обьект2',
        value: 17
    }
];
for (let i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
  var a = mas1.find(item => item.nameObj == mas[i]);
  console.log(a? a.value : "not found");
}
```

Comment: item.nameObj это будет 'обьект4' правильно ?

Answer (score 1):

Цикл `for` для подобных целей менее удобен, чем метод [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
// решение (функция поиска в массиве объектов по значению св-ва)
const findObjectByProp = (objArr, propName, propVal) => {
  return objArr.find(o => o[propName] === propVal); 
}; 

// использование
const mas = ['объект1', 'объект2', 'объект3', 'объект4'];
const mas1 = [
  { nameObj: 'объект4', value: 14 },
  { nameObj: 'объект1', value: 16 },
  { nameObj: 'объект2', value: 17 }
];
let i = 1;
const found = findObjectByProp(mas1, 'nameObj', mas[i]); 
if (found)
  console.log(found.value);
```

---

А если надо преобразовать массив значений одного свойства в массив значений другого, то это можно за 2 прохода (один проход на каждый входной массив) - вот так:

```js
const mapToAnotherProp = (valArr, srcProp, objArr, dstProp) => {
  const dict = objArr.reduce(
    (rslt, obj) => rslt.set(obj[srcProp], obj[dstProp])
  , new Map()); 
  return valArr.map(val => dict.get(val)); 
}; 

const mas = ['объект1', 'объект2', 'объект3', 'объект4'];
const mas1 = [
  { nameObj: 'объект4', value: 14 },
  { nameObj: 'объект1', value: 16 },
  { nameObj: 'объект2', value: 17 }
];
const result = mapToAnotherProp(mas, 'nameObj', mas1, 'value'); 
console.log(result);
```